# Recommendations for additional transient voltage/current protection

Tags: protection, transient-suppression

I'm working on a device that uses an Arduino Nano to interface with an [RSSV013010W0101-U1930 Proximity Sensor](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Harvatek%20PDFs/RSSV013010W0101-U1930.pdf) (located on a remote board and connect with 4-wire cable), and display relevant information on a standard 16x2 hd44780 LCD.

[image: device schematic]

[image: proximity sensor remote board]

I have a working PCB version of it, but a previous version was consistently damaging the proximity sensor. The device showed signs of a short circuit, but no shorts could be detected on a continuity test.

Since the only real difference between the PCB version and the breadboard version was the power supply (breadboard used Nano USB for 5V power supply, while PCB used 12V DC external supply with an [L4940V5 Linear  5V Regulator](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/c5/1b/3d/dc/81/d8/4f/d7/CD00000442.pdf/files/CD00000442.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000442.pdf)), I determined the cause was likely inadequate transient protection and rectified that problem in the current version.

So far the new version hasn't damaged a proximity sensor, but I was hoping to get additional recommendations for transient voltage and current protection, if needed.